# Error insalling webpack with npm

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install

I wanted to start working on React today, and I found this tutorial to help me setting up my environment:

https://www.kirupa.com/react/setting_up_react_environment.htm

Everything went well, up to the point where I am supposed to install webpack: npm just nope me. I absolutly don't know how to fix this.

I tried two commands to install Webpack:
This one, in the tutorial: npm install webpack --save
and this one, coming from npmjs.com: npm install --save-dev webpack

Both return the same errors, which are the following:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyAwesomeApp>npm install --save-dev webpack
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev"
"webpack"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\core-util
is\1.0.2\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '�' at 1:1
npm ERR! �D$�    I�D$�I�D$�I�D$�    I�L$�I�D$�    I�D$�I�D$�I�D$�    I�$   
I�\$�H��8�e
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\core-util
is\1.0.2\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyAwesomeApp\npm-debug.log
```

If anyone know how to fix this problem, or know a setting up tutorial that works for sure, I would be glad, React seems really interesting to learn.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Try running  `npm cache clean`  and then install webpack again
.Check for trailing commas in any of the objects in your package.json
mostly under 'dependencies' object.

Comment: Also check for any uppercase letters in "name" key under package.json

Answer (score 0):

There problems in `package.json` at installed package, your log dump:

> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\core-utilis\1.0.2\package\package.json
>
> package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript

Check it content (may be usefull any online json validator. I have seen special `package.json` validators)

The `package.json` must be plain `JSON` format file.

Seems it corrupt. Mey be need to reinstall. Do you have mirrored double drive hard disk or may be file system corrupted. May be some package installation process was interrupted.

The package.json [description](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) for references.

Comment: I just tried that validator: http://jsonlint.com/                                                The JSON is valid according to it. Anyway, I didn't meddle with the package.json myself: It was auto-generated by `npm init`. I then used `npm install react react-dom --save` to install react, so everything was taken care of from npm, and only this (in all honesty, i don't know a thing about JSON)

Comment: I rewrite answer seems you have problems with installed packages. may be some installation process was interrupted.